# How does one get pdb.trace() working in unittest?

Tags: python, python-unittest, pdb

I am running commands such as:

```
python3 -m unittest -v -b core.tests.tests.TestApplication.test_name
```

This freezes whenever it gets to `import pdb()`, `pdb.set_trace()`.

Is there a way I can modify the code so that we can use debugger?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to remove -b, which buffers the string output.